# Java "OR", having problems

Tags: java, if-statement

My problem is next:

I need to check if program.version (major, minor) is 1.5 (where 1 is major, 5 is minor version) or higher, or lower... So I need some something like this:

```
if (major < 2 && minor > 4) || (major > 1 ) // if version is higher then 1.5 or 2
{
//code//
}
if (major < 2 && minor < 5)
{
//code//
}
```

The problem is in "||", it reports the syntax error on token "||"... and I don't know how to solve the problem. Any help please?!

Comment: `major < 2 && minor > 4` this won't ever satisfy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're parenthese are wrong.

```
if ( (major < 2 && minor > 4) || (major > 1) ) // if version is higher then 1.5 or 2
{
//code//
}
if (major < 2 && minor < 5)
{
//code//
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You've only forgot a parenthesis..

`if ((major < 2 && minor > 4) || (major > 1 ))`

Answer (score 3):

you're missing the parathesis on the first if statement line

make it

```
if ((major < 2 && minor > 4) || (major > 1 ))
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java "if" expression always must be enclosed in brackets.

Just change for

```
if ((major < 2 && minor > 4) || (major > 1 ))
{
//code//
}
```

and your compiler will be happy.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

check your brackets -

```
if ((major < 2 && minor > 4) || (major > 1 ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing a set of brackets. The expression being testing in the if-statement must be surrounded by brackets e.g.

```
    if ((major < 2 && minor > 4) || (major > 1 )) // if version is higher then 1.5 or 2
    {
    //code//
    }
    if (major < 2 && minor < 5)
    {
    //code//
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for major and minor seperately, just multiply your version with either 100 or 1000 and then have your comparision numbers accordingly.

Comment: @CRT_flow - haha.. anyway just a case of missing paranthesis, which I failed to notice too. But lot other people have noticed :)